# OR of pairwise XOR

Tags: algorithm

Can anyone suggest me a `O(n)` algorithm for `OR` the result of pairwise `XOR` operations on N numbers for example let `N=3` and numbers be `5,7` and `9`

```
5 ^ 7 = 2,  7 ^ 9 = 14,  9 ^ 5 = 12
2|14|12 = 14
```

`^ for XOR` operation and `| for OR` operation

Comment: Haven't you given one?

Comment: @Beta The brute force algorithm is O(n^2), because you need perform n*(n-1) XOR operations.

Comment: Why? Just arrange the numbers in a ring and do n XOR operations between neighbors, you'll get exactly the same result. (I thought that was what you were doing in your example.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `A[i]` differs from `A[j]` in `k`-th bit then:
either `A[i]` differs from `A[1]` in `k`-th bit
or `A[j]` differs from `A[1]` in `k`-th bit
So, N operations are enough:

```
// A[i] = array of source numbers, i=1..N
Result = 0
for i = 2 to N
    Result = Result OR (A[i] XOR A[1])
print(Result)
```

Comment: Thanks, Egor your solution was completely awesome and worked for me

Answer (score 5):

The bits are independent, so you can compute the result for each bit separately.

So given a sequence of bits, we want to now the OR of all pairswise XORs. The OR is 1 iif at least one of the bitwise XORs is 1. This is the case iif you have at least one 0 and at least one 1 in your input sequence. It is very easy to check whether this is the case.

Total time: *O(wN)* where w is the maximum bit length of any of your input numbers.

Assuming that *w* is smaller than the word size, we can also solve it in *O(N)*: Just solve all bits in parallel:

```
have_one = 0
have_zero = 0
for x in input:
    have_one |= x
    have_zero |= ~x
return have_one & have_zero
```

`have_one` has a bit set exactly at those positions where we have a 1 somewhere in the input. `have_zero` has a bit set exactly at those positions where we have a 0 somewhere in the input. The result is 1 for those positions where both is the case.